# Call Log or now called Recent Calls

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, call-history

Where did the ability to sort and see your calls either by missed calls (those that you did not answer), received calls (those that you answered) and Dialed calls (those that you dialed.) There is no menu selection to choose like in previous versions of Google's Android System.

Answer (score 2):

Open the phone app and open the Call History tab. (Icon is a clock.)

If you're using Google Voice tap the word "Inbox" at the top of the screen and it will pull down a menu of the different boxes for GV (e.g., Text, Missed, Received, etc.)

Comment: I think he means filtering this list by the criteria he mentions, i.e. three separate lists...

Comment: Doesn't exist. Might be an app that does that.